# Access to Serial IO I2C Host Controller in windows

Tags: driver, hardware, i2c

Access to Serial IO I2C Host Controller - 5AAC
We connected an FRAM to I2C Host Controller and we want to access to the FRAM via I2C.
Our system is Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 64-bit.
Processor: Intel(R) ATom(TM) Processor E3930
Target device name: Intel(R) Serial IO I2C Host Contoroller - 5AAC
Installed driver: iaLPSS2i_I2C.sys

My understanding of Windows is very little.
Could you give me an idea for that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcPMM.png)

Comment: Write the proper driver for your hardware, isn't it obvious?

Comment: Hi 0andriy
can you tell me how to generate driver for my hardware?

Comment: No idea, I'm not a Windows guy, sorry.