# Accessing Onboard I2C-Controller from Windows10 Professional

Tags: windows, iot, i2c, bus

we want to use a single board computer (C582S-IM-AA), which has an I2C Controller, because we have some I2C slave ICs which, drive some LEDs and inputs and outputs.

The OS should be Windows10 Professional, because we have an application that runs on it.
So my question is: can I access the C582S-IM-AA's onboard I2C-Controller from Windows Pro version.

All Examples and articles, I found, use Windows IoT and I'm not shure what's the difference. (When I look into my laptops W10 Pro Device-Manager, I can see some I2C Host Controllers under System Devices, but how to use them?)

Until now we used a Mainboard from Congatec, and they supplied a C and C# library to access the onboard I2C-Bus from Windows10 Pro, which worked like a charm.

So maybe someone has experiences with I2C on Windows10 Pro (Libs, Native APIs, ). Or maybe my idea is totally stupid? Or maybe all functionality of Win Pro is also availlable in Win IoT, so that we can switch to it?

Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to add "Hello developers," at the beginnning of the question, but its not possible, so: Hello developers

Comment: There are some resources on the web on how to access these, but I couldn't find something concrete so far (and I have no such hardware to test). Maybe this thread gives some hints: https://github.com/dotnet/iot/issues/1411 (towards the end, it drifts off to a completely unrelated topic, so be sure to read from the top)

Comment: Thank you, another guy has asked a very similar question, but no sensful answer:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66773763/access-to-serial-io-i2c-host-controller-in-windows)

Comment: I'm sure the team at https://github.com/dotnet/iot/ would be happy to take help in getting this to work, but it seems somebody with the corresponding hardware needs to do the first step.

Comment: I also looked at a sample from [ms-iot](https://github.com/ms-iot), which exactly adressed my problem. I could it get to run on Win10Pro, but it didnt found any I²C-controller. Another problem is, that it is (maybe has to be) an UWP-App, which is not possible in our project. 
For the moment, we use an USB-I²C-adapter (FTDI FT232H), the library support is excellent. But it would be nicer, to use onbord capabilities.

Comment: That is undoubtedly true. It's really just that nobody has had the possibility and time to implement this. And I2C controllers on desktop PCs are still rare. But FTDI chips are a good alternative (or, if it needs to be more powerful, you can use something like an Arduino Nano for the same)

Comment: I have pinged the relevant people, and someone at MS is (supposed to) look into the issue. But I can't say anything about whether that's going to be solved and when.

Comment: Thank you for careing and sharing. I'm not shure if it doesnt work somehow. I only dont know how. As I wrote in the question, the guys from congatec support theyr onboard I2C Controller under W10Pro with a c++- and a (wrapping) c# dll. How did they do this?

Comment: Is that library downloadable somewhere (ideally with source)?

Comment: Sorry, was on vacation. Yes it's downloadable from various congatec product pages, like [Mini-ITX-Board](https://www.congatec.com/en/products/mini-itx/conga-ic370/) It's called CGOS API, but I'm afraid, there are no sources. They provide for Linux, Windows, C++, CLR and Python. It does more than only acessing the I²C-Bus.